# Recursion Function Return

Tags: c++

```
int gcd(int a,int b){   
    if(b==0)
      return a;
    else if(a<b)
        gcd(b,a);
    else
        gcd(b,a%b);
}
```

In this recursive function a error is there which says:

```
control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because you're only returning any value if `b==0`. Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.

Comment: use `return gcd(b,a%b)` also `return gcd(b,a)`

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the return value from the recursive calls to `gcd()`. The only place you return anything from the function is if `b == 0`. Any other value of b will cause the `gcd()` to be invoked recursively, but then execution will just run right off the end of the function, returning nothing.
Change your calls of `gcd()` to `return gcd( b, a );` and `return gcd( b, a % b );` and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `return` to return a value. Instead of `if else`, you can use a single `return` statement and an expression involving the tertiary operator. You may then also want to make this a [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) function

```
inline constexpr int gcd(int a, int b) noexcept
{
  return b==0? a: a<b? gcd(b,a) : gcd(b,a%b);
}
```

allowing compile-time manipulations involving `gcd()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this?

Your code has 3 paths, and 1 'return'.  Ask yourself, 'why do the 2 recursive gcd() calls if their computations are dropped / ignored / discarded.'

Your code is as if you wrote:

```
int gcd(int a,int b)
{   
   if(b==0)     { return a; }            // ok
   else if(a<b) { (void) gcd(b, a); }    // error here
   else         { (void) gcd(b, (a%b)) } // error here
}
```

---

This re-write has 3 paths and 3 return statements:

```
int gcd(int a,int b)
{   
   if    (0 == b) { return a;             }
   else if(a < b) { return gcd(b,   a  ); }
   else           { return gcd(b, (a%b)); }
}
```

It is 'better'.

---

Perhaps my preferred style (not-so 'structured', with single return, but multiple breaks in loop) simplifies the issue even more?

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{   
   int retVal = a; 

   do {

      if(b == 0) {   /* already done */    break; }

      if(a  < b) { retVal = gcd(b,   a  ); break; }

      {            retVal = gcd(b, (a%b)); break; };

   } while(0);  // single pass 'loop'

   return (retVal);  // single return - gcd() is defined to return an int
}
```

I've gotten used to this, and still resist multiple returns.

Comment: A single return, ok, sure.  That's mostly opinion, but a valid position to hold.  But a do/while(0) with breaks?  That's hardly well-structured code.

Comment: Two quick comments - first, my main problem wasn't with the single return, but with the rest of the structure of the function.  2nd - as with many dogmatic positions, "single return" can quickly lead to excessively convoluted code while you bend over backwards to avoid returning more than once.